# Custom Font not look good with special characters in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uifont

I am facing an issue while applying custom font files(.ttf or .otf)to my table cell font style,it  does'nt look good with special characters (ie "à"), strange thing is that it really works with `UILabel` . Here is my code

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"HistoryCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (cell==nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton];
     //cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow"]];
     cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.9647058824 green:0.9647058824 blue:0.9647058824 alpha:1];
}

UIFont* font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"EK03Serif-B01" size:18];
cell.textLabel.font=font;

NSArray *chapterName = [[fileList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]componentsSeparatedByString:@".doc"];
cell.textLabel.text=[chapterName objectAtIndex:0];


return cell;
}
```

Fore more please see below screenshot.
[image]

Comment: can you try putting the device in french langiuage and see how the font works ?

Comment: Maybe your font doesn't contain these characters and the browser/display falls back to another font.

Comment: @Mr.T I have tried with french language but still same.. :(

Comment: Can you try with a different font to see if the result is the same?